# What happens to photos that you edit using iPhoto for iOS?

Tags: ios, photos.app

If I use iPhoto for iOS to edit a photo from my photostream or one of the albums which is synched from my desktop iPhoto library, it shows up in a special "edited" album in iPhoto for iOS.

Is there a way to have the edited version sent back to my computer? Or accessed from the iOS Photos app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you tap the "Share" icon, you have the option to send photos to the Camera Roll or to share them with iTunes:

[image]

This interface is quite flexible, you can send the currently selected photos, all the photos, or choose the photos you want to share. Sharing with iTunes creates a folder in the "Apps" section of your device in iTunes that you can save from:

[image]

Comment: Might this answer also address this question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/is-there-an-app-that-allows-users-to-take-multiple-photos-and-upload-them-all-to